# Login page should always be front page

Tags: php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

The above code is located in index.php.
index.php opens as front page but what I want is a login page that should be the front page. Without login to the login page the index.php page should not be accessible.

Once the login done the user is redirected to the index.php.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: `but what should be done to make login page as front page`: Work

Comment: what are you storing in session variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `index.php`, check if the user has logged in. If not, redirect to login page.

You can use `$_SESSION[variable]` to keep the track of login which will help you to check in the `index.php` page.

Comment: $_SESSION["user_name"] = $row[Name];

Comment: @user3475159 If you have that already, in your `index.php`, just do: `if(!$_SESSION["user_name"]) { /* redirect to login page */ }`

Answer (score 0):

Make your 'after login' page something other than index.php, since the webserver will normally serve that as the first page in a given directory

and in the event of not having a login then use on your other pages something along the lines of:

```
header("Location: index.php");
```

Comment: but when i open in wamp server it always open index.php page as front page..

Comment: Maybe try    include("login.php")  from your index.php page

Answer (score 0):

this code assumes that you are saving `email` in your session variable, if not change accordingly

```
 if ($_SESSION['email'] =='') {
     header("Location:login.php");
    }
     else
    {
    header("Location:index.php");
    }
```

Comment: it is not redirecting to index.php

Comment: does your session contains email? did you logged out and tested code?

Comment: yes email but saved as username

Comment: if ($_SESSION['username '] =='')